# How could I get api cache with external query (not with ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The query response is not from ActiveRecord

and the response is in JSON format.

How could I cache the return result

```
  def get_drug_usage_history_by_symptoms
      pipeline_work = [
      {"$unwind" => "$records"},
      {'$match' => {'records.items' => {'$in' => items} }},
      {'$limit' => 8 } # FOR DEVELOPMENT USE
    ]
      cur = db[collection].find.aggregate(pipeline_work).allow_disk_use(true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: cur.to_a }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides a generic low-level data cache that I've found extremely useful for caching API call results and so forth. Learn about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch). Basically this is how it works:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("unique_key_for_this_data", expires_in: 30.minutes) do
  # make the API call
  # Whatever value this block returns, will be stored in the cache
  # If the value is already cached (and not expired), that value
  # will be provided and this block won't even execute
end
```